# copy file data in int array

Tags: c++, linux

I want to ask that I have a file in which number are written in rows and columns:

```
23 54 433 65 23 
44 3  32  422 43
```

I want to copy then in two dimensional int array, but I have no idea how to do it. i thought to apply a string token function,  but how to apply it i have no idea what to do kindly guide me a little bit

thanks

Comment: Check out this earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925887/splitting-up-lines-into-ints

Comment: thanks sir but i am not using vector is there any other way kindly help me

Comment: Your earlier question about 2D arrays now contains URL links to earlier questions that should help you. The question I cited above covers reading of `int` values from a text file. If you are hoping somebody will just write the code for you, you are probably out of luck.

Comment: You should use vector. A vector can be used as an int array. &v[0] is the same as a int[] or int*.

Answer (score 0):

There are two answers to this question.  One of them is pretty straightforward (and assumes that you know the number of columns and rows of the input file in question).

```
for (int a=0; a<NUMROW; a++)
    for (int b=0; b<NUMCOL; b++)
        cin>>TWODARRAY[a][b];
```

So that was pretty easy.  For a variable length of data input, the long and ungainly answer I came up with is a bit more exciting.  Still, I've tested it, and it works.  Hope everyone's comfortable with pointers to pointers and stringstreams.

```
string in;
int** twoDArray=NULL;
int numRow=0;
int numCol=0;
string** inputHold=NULL;
int inputSize=10;
//Since we're using pointers instead of vectors, 
    //we have to keep track of the end of the array.
inputHold=new string*[inputSize]; 
while (getline(cin,in)){
    //The string in now contains a line of input.
    if (numRow==0)
    //Assuming that the number of inputs per column is the same in each row,
            //we can save on computation by only checking the number of columns once.
    //Performance may be improved here- it might be more efficient to use str.find
        for (string::iterator iter=in.begin(); iter!=in.end(); iter++){
            if (*iter==' ')
                numCol++;
        }
    //Store the string
    inputHold[numRow]=new string(in);

    numRow++;
    if (numRow==inputSize) {
        //If we're at the end of the array, we create a bigger one and repopulate the data.
        string** tmpInput=inputHold;
        int oldsize=inputSize;
        inputSize=inputSize*2;
        inputHold=new string*[inputSize];
        for (int i=0; i<oldsize; i++){
            inputHold[i]=tmpInput[i];
        }
    }
}
//The method that I used to determine the number of columns is mildly flawed-
    //it doesn't account for the end of line.  So, we increment the counter.
numCol=numCol+1;
twoDArray=new int*[numRow];
for (int a=0; a<numRow; a++)
    twoDArray[a]=new int[numCol];
for (int a=0; a<numRow; a++){
    istringstream parser(*(inputHold[a]));
    for (int b=0; b<numCol; b++){
        parser>>twoDArray[a][b];
    }
}

for (int a=0; a<numRow; a++)
    for (int b=0; b<numCol; b++)
        cout<<twoDArray[a][b]<<endl;
```

Anyone got anything less complicated?